# Trying to redirect file contents to display a specific line provided by command line arguements in C

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments, readfile, io-redirection

I am using gcc compiler.I have a file called lines.txt and i am trying to have the user enter an invocation like **./lines 4 < lines.txt** to display only line number 4 of the text file. So far i have it so that if the user enters **./lines 4 lines.txt** without the redirection, it displays the 4th line of the text file. I can't get it to work like this with redirection though. I also am using a makefile to compile and clean the code. This is my code so far:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

// argv[0] contains the file name
char *str1 = argv[0];       // storing the file name
char *str2 = "./lines";
int ret;


        if(strstr(buff, argv[1]) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", buff); /* ...such as show it on the screen */
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);  /* close the file */ 

    }
}
```

**My current output without redirection is:**

~/Desktop/project3 $ ./lines 4 lines.txt

First arg is: ./lines

Second arg is: 4

Third arg is: lines.txt

Read file name correctly. File contains:

Line 4

Comment: To add to what @user3121023 just said, your task is not to compare str1 & str2 but to determine if there is a second argument, which would indicate the user is providing the filename, or not, which would mean the file is provided via STDIN... then use the appropriate FILE * in your fgets().

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So how would i display stdin using a while loop line by line? I am new to C and am not understanding how.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Perhaps:  `if (argc == 1 )
{
    fp = stdin; 
}else{ 
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r"); 
    if( fp == NULL )
    { 
        exit(1); 
    }
}   
`

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It seems to be missing several lines after the declaration of the `ret` variable.

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter actually exists.

Comment: the parameter: `argv[0]` contains the name of the file being executed, not the first command line parameter.  The first command line parameter is found by the pointer in `argv[1]`.